# CS0212 or how to set pointer to property

Tags: c#

I have class

```
public class ForAllViewModel
  {
    byte abn;
    byte abn2;
    public ObservableCollection<TArrF> a
    public class TArrF
      {
        public unsafe byte* Yk;
      }  
 }
```

when I wrote

```
a[1].Yk = &abn;
a[2].Yk = &abn2;
abn =1;
abn2 = 0;
```

it gives me error

> error CS0212: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer.

All I want is after

```
(*a[1].Yk)+=1;
(*a[2].Yk)+=1;
Console.WriteLine(abn.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(abn2.ToString());
```

to see in log `2` and `1`.
Yes, I saw

```
fixed (byte* p = &abn) { a[1].Yk = p; }
```

but with this in log `1` and `0`.
Update:
Ok, I will try to explain my task.
On form/window I have many CheckBoxes. Every CheckBox assign to FieldName and TableName of Data Base. It is used for dynamically build SQL query.
I use counter like 'abn' to count how many fields are used for specific table.
For example:
CheckBox1 assign to Field1 and Table1
CheckBox2 assign to Field2 and Table1
CheckBox3 assign to Field1 and Table2
When CheckBox is Checked counter 'abn' increase by 1. If counter > 0 I add Table1 to my SQL query and specific field. When CheckBox is Unchecked counter decrease by 1. If counter = 0 I remove Table1 from SQL query.
And I solved this task in Delphi with pointers. And now I start porting this project to C# and stuck on this.
Yes, I understand that it requires 'fixed', but as I wrote 'fixed (byte* p = &abn) { a[1].Yk = p; }' doesnt give me right result.
Because when I do '*a[1].Yk+=1;' 'abn' also should become for 1 greater. But it doesnt. It means I set pointer in wrong way. So I search right way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    byte abn, abn2;
    public class Field
    {
       public string Table;
       public string Field;
       public unsafe byte* Yk;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Field> a;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        a = new ObservableCollection<Field>();
        abn = 0;
        abn = 0;
        a.Add(new Field());
        a.Add(new Field());
        a.Add(new Field());
        a.Add(new Field());
        a[1].Table="Table_1";
        a[1].Field="Field_1";
        a[2].Table="Table_1";
        a[2].Field="Field_2";
        a[3].Table="Table_2";
        a[3].Field="Field_1";
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p = &abn) { a[1].Yk = p; }
            fixed (byte* p = &abn) { a[2].Yk = p; }
            fixed (byte* p = &abn2) { a[3].Yk = p; }
        }
    }

    private void CheckEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.EditValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            Console.WriteLine("abn BEFORE modification: "+abn.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("abn2 BEFORE modification: " + abn2.ToString());
            DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit cb = sender as DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit;
            byte i = Convert.ToByte(cb.Tag);
            if ((bool)cb.IsChecked)
            {
                *a[i].Yk += 1;
                //if(*a[i].Yk==1) { addTabletoSQL(a[i].Table);} 
                //addFieldtoSQL(a[i].Field);
            }
            else
            {
                *a[i].Yk -= 1;
                //if(*a[i].Yk==0) { removeTablefromSQL(a[i].Table);} 
                //removeFieldfromSQL(a[i].Field);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("abn AFTER modification: " + abn.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("abn2 AFTER modification: " + abn2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Add some lines to more clear how I see project should work (and how it works in Delphi) and xaml

```
<Grid>
    <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Content="Field 1" Tag="1" EditValueChanged="CheckEdit_EditValueChanged" />
    <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Content="Field 2" Tag="2" EditValueChanged="CheckEdit_EditValueChanged"  />
    <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Content="Field 3" Tag="3" EditValueChanged="CheckEdit_EditValueChanged"  />
</Grid>
```

So, when I Check CheckBoxes abn=2 and abn2=1. It`a right. But when I Unchecked - abn and abn2 should become 0, but its dont
[second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPHN0.png)

Comment: @Sinatr Sorry, CS0212 ofcourse

Comment: how can i mention your name in comments, its weird syntax

Comment: @MidTwo, you don't need to, he is "OP" (original poster) ;)

Comment: @MidTwo you can write Igor

Comment: I don't understand the question. You see the error message. It seems reasonably clear to me. You _must_ use `fixed` if you want to take the address of your unfixed expression. Please explain _precisely_ and _clearly_ what it is you want the code to do, that you are unable to get it to do. Also explain similarly what _specifically_ you are having trouble with; why is the error message not enough information for you to fix the code. Also provide a good [mcve] that completely illustrates all of this.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do but, almost certainly, using pointers to do it is the wrong approach.

Comment: Even though your *project* may use WPF, I don't understand how your *question* is related to WPF. Generally, pointers should only be used for language crossing reasons, not in order to do something in C# as if you where programming C / C++

Comment: @PeterDuniho I edit topic

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is 100% clear now, that you don't need pointer type at all. Rethink the design a little. Why do you need both, the static `abn` and the collection `TArrF` values? Most probably you can live with only one of them. If you need the replication, consider wrapping the `abn` properties in a container class and have an array of those containers - this way, if the value within the container is increased / decreased, it will be reflected in all usage places

Comment: @grek40 collection TArrF has all fields. With CheckBox.Tag I can access to specific item of this collection in one procedure like "OnEditValueChanged". Please look at 1st topic, I added full example code how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a small change to your code in this answer, however I'd actually advise to redesign larger parts of your application in order to make it fit with the WPF architecture.

Instead of your code

```
byte abn, abn2;
public class Field
{
   public unsafe byte* Yk;
}
public ObservableCollection<Field> a;
```

You could use:

```
FieldCount abn, abn2;
public class FieldCount
{
    public byte Count { get; set; }
}
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FieldCount Yk { get; set; }
}
public ObservableCollection<Field> a;
```

Then change your initialization accordingly:

```
a = new ObservableCollection<Field>();
abn = new FieldCount { Count = 0 };
// note I assume you don't want to double initialize abn
abn2 = new FieldCount { Count = 0 };
// add fields to the collection
a.Add(new Field { Name = "Field X", Yk = abn });
a.Add(new Field { Name = "Field Y", Yk = abn });
a.Add(new Field { Name = "Field Z", Yk = abn2 });
a.Add(new Field());
```

And change the checked event handler

```
private void CheckEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.EditValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("abn BEFORE modification: " + abn.Count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("abn2 BEFORE modification: " + abn2.Count.ToString());

    var cb = sender as DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit;
    byte i = Convert.ToByte(cb.Tag);

    if ((bool)cb.IsChecked)
    {
        a[i].Yk.Count += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        a[i].Yk.Count -= 1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("abn AFTER modification: " + abn.Count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("abn2 AFTER modification: " + abn2.Count.ToString());
}
```

Hope I didn't add any typos, can't compile my changes right now.

Comment: It works, but It will not work for my task.  I wrote
public class Field
{
   public byte Count { get; set; }
}
as short example. Full Class look like this
public class TArrF
        {
            public virtual bool Checked { get; set; } = false;
            public string Field;
            public string Table;
            public string Usl;
            public int Ind; //used for create order of fields
            public unsafe byte* Yk;
            public unsafe byte* Fil;
        }

Comment: and when I will set for a[1].Field="Field1" and a[2].Field="Field2" in a[1].Field also become "Field2" because it is the same object, so your option doesnt approach me. But nevertheless thanks. I still think pointers is my option....

Comment: @ИгорьРадченко Its not pointers... its nested objects. See my update for a way to specify properties per field and assign counters that are the same for some fields and different for others. As already said, you probably NEVER EVER need `unsafe` as long as you stay within the realm of C#

Comment: A side note: with my approach, you would probably make `Table` a property in `FieldCount`, since if `Yk` is the same, `Table` should also be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day!) Now it works as should)